# Retrieving null value in slicing 2d python numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I need to slice a python numpy array for multiplication. The slicing I need to be in the below format

```
    first_slice_matrixA=[0,1]
    second_slice_matriA=[2,3]
    first_slice_matrixB=[0,2]
    second_slice_matrixB=[1,3]
```

Below is my code for slicing. For the first slice its working but for second it returns a null array.

```
   matrix_A = np.arange(4).reshape(2,2)
   matrix_B=np.arange(4).reshape(2,2)
   A_1=matrix_A[0:1, 0:2]
   A_2=matrix_A[1:1, 0:2]
   print(A_2)
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: `[i:i]` makes empty slice, whatever `i` value is

Comment: The `repr` display of `A_2` is more informative:  `array([], shape=(0, 2), dtype=int64)`.  See the 0 in the shape?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use same index for start and stop, the slice is empty, whatever the
index is. You'd do the following so see your values

- first index is vertical slicing, so it selects 'rows'
- second index is horizontal slicing, so it selects 'columns'

```
m = np.arange(4).reshape(2,2)

# horizontal
print(m[0:1, :]) # [[0 1]]
print(m[1:2, :]) # [[2 3]]

# vertical
print(m[:, 0:1]) # [[0] [2]]
print(m[:, 1:2]) # [[1] [3]]
```

Note that here, because of size 2

```
m[0:1, :] == m[:1, :]
m[1:2, :] == m[1:, :]
```

Comment: Hi @azro, what would for matrix B if slicing vertically. Thanks

Comment: Hi @azro or instance for matrix B I want the matrix_B1=[0,2] and for matrix_B2=[1,3].